# ggplot Basic Formatting Issues?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large DF that has columns (below is just a sample):

```
Identity: "T4", "T4", "T4", "TNBC", "TNBC, "Control", "Control"
IdentityColor: "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green"
```

PC_1 and PC_2: Have some values associated with above variables for Principal Component Analysis.

I just need a scatter plot with:
1. Identity (T4, TNBC and Control)
2. The colors that correspond to the group.
3. black border around the points (Shape=21)

The code I feel that should work isn't working and is below:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(PC_1, PC_2, fill=Identity))+

geom_point(shape=21, size=2)+

scale_fill_manual(values=unique(as.character(DF$IdentityColor
```

But the graph I get has the colors assigned to the wrong group!
Note: I can't do it manually because for some DFs I have upwards of 18 groups.

[Figure of the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEhDg.png)

Comment: Are you looking for `scale_fill_identity()`? That takes the values as literal colours

Comment: Gives me an error that says there is no color by name: T4-- I am parsing IdentityColor into the Scale_fill_identity argument and it's still not right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a problem of syntax more than anything.  In short, the `values=` for any `scale_` command are expected as a list, not a dataframe.  Forcing dataframe to a list does not quite work out, so it's best to create that explicitly.  For example:

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(
  x=1:20,
  y=rnorm(20),
  grp=sample(c('T4','TNBC','Control'),20,replace=TRUE)
)

color_list <- list("T4"="red", "TNBC"="blue", "Control"="green")

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=grp)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=color_list)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  As it is pointed out in the comment, a list is not strictly required, but a named entity is important to ensure the color is associated to the specific label.  If you change `list(` to `c(` in the example above, it works just the same.  You can supply a character vector as well, but with that, colors are assigned based on the ordering of the levels in the `fill=` aesthetic as a factor.  You can use this to your advantage in your original example by creating a character vector that has the ordering properly setup based on the levels of the fill aesthetic.

Comment: For this usage, it matters that what's given to the `values` argument is named, with the data labels as the names, but it doesn't need to be a `list`. If you replace your `list` with `c` and make an ordinary named `character` vector the code will work just as well. (And `character` vectors can be easier to work with than `list`s.)

Comment: yes - good point.  Just as long as it is named.  If the OP supplies an unnamed character vector, the colors are just assigned based on the ordering of the `levels` of the `fill=` aesthetic as a factor.

Comment: Thank you-- I made it according to a named list. It just would be cumbersome if there were a lot of groups...